# Can't query one_to_many relationship with Sequel gem?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I'm using the Sequel gem on a Postgres database (using Ruby).

I have a one_to_many relationship between the class "Home" and the class "Person". So, many people are in a home.

I've got my class schema defined as such:

```
class Home < Sequel::Model
  one_to_many :person
end

class Person < Sequel::Model
  many_to_one :home
end
```

I've got a selection of people (`p = Person.where(:age => 20)`) and now I'm trying to query the homes that those people are in, using `Home.where(:persons => p)`. However, I'm getting the error `column "persons" does not exist`.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change `one_to_many :persons` in your model. And collect your homes with this:

```
p.map { |person| person.home }
```